# FosElastica index on ManyToMany relation update

Tags: symfony, foselasticabundle

I use FOSElatica Bundle in my Symfony Application.

I've 2 Entities, with a ManyToOne relation like this:

Strain
    OneToMany on Tube

Tube
    ManyToOne on Strain

I would want when a user change a Tube, that index the Strain in FOSElastica, but FOSElastica Listen on Doctrine events to index in Elasticsearch, and a ManyToOne Relation don't active the trigger on Strain.

I think a good way is to do a Listener/Subscriber on Tube to call a function that manually index the attached Strain.

But I don't know which service inject in the Subscriber, and how to manually index in FOSElastica.

Answer (score 0):

I can use this in my controller:
$this->container->get('fos_elastica.object_persister.index.type')->replaceOne($entity);

$this->container->get('fos_elastica.object_persister.index.type')->replaceMany([$entity1, $entity2, $entity3]);